# Frequency vs Flux data for Gamma Ray Bursts (GRB190114C)

Tags: gamma-ray-bursts, raw-data

I am working on a research project to prove [Synchrotron-Self-Compton radiation](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fde.m.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSynchrotron-Selbst-Compton-Modell) through the case study of [GRB190114C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRB_190114C) and am not able to find data for the frequency spectrum even though all telescoped capture frequency data. I need it to plot a flux density vs frequency graph.

I have looked through many public telescope databases such as https://www.swift.ac.uk/analysis/xrt/

Does anyone have any idea where I could maybe get this data from? Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to astronomy SE! It would be great if you linked an English-speaking introduction to SSC radiation - I only found the German wikipage.

Comment: You may be trying to use radio based terminology/think to gamma-ray bursts which are nearly exclusively observed in the x-ray spectral region. Normally x-ray astronomy uses energy as the wavelength/frequency axis. It would be possible to convert a spectrum from say (energy) keV to frequency. You may want to look at the SED (Spectral Energy Density) plot for your gamma-ray burst, if there is multi-wavelength obs.